# How do I fatten someone up?

Tags: the-sims-3

I want to fatten up my Sim with the "Athletic" trait, but nothing seems to work.

I've tried to prevent my sim from getting exercise and stuffed him with loads of ice cream, but he just won't get fat. Do I have to use body sculptor in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you make your Sim eat when they have the 'Stuffed' moodlet, which is gained from eating while the hunger bar is full, they will gradually get fatter.

Answer (score 0):

if the solution of walrus helmet doesnt work you could alternatively go to the hospital and make a plastic surgery. It costs money but it opens the create a sim window so you cna change your sim as you wish